# Need help with replacing a headphone jack

Tags: repair, headphones

I have found a ton of guides to do this, but i don't have a store bought connector so i simply ripped the stock one open.
It looks like this (found the pic on the internet, not mine): http://static.flickr.com/3147/2406438104_5a687610dd.jpg

Apart from which wire goes where i'm confused about the color coding on my cable. Usually i'd run into a red/white/copper wire but these aren't like that, these have a blue wire, a green wire and a red wire so i have no way of telling which one is which.
I'd really appreciate some assistance on this.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is related to repair of an electronic device rather than the design of one.

Comment: I opened the thread on this website because i saw a question just like mine. So does this rule only apply to certain people?

Comment: Nope! Link the question and we'll close that one as well.

Comment: Here's the question i told you about: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6698/headphone-wire-color-coding

Answer (score 1):

Since you are replacing a existing jack, look at how that is connected and then connect the new jack the same way.  Use a ohmmeter or continuity tester to figure out which wires on the new jack connect to which parts.

The outer conductor is ground, and the tip and small ring below the tip the two audio channels.  I don't remember which one is left and right off the top of my head, but that's surely something easy to find after a few seconds searching the net.

Comment: Ok, i ripped the stock sleeve off, unfortunately ripping off 2 wires in the process. The red one goes to the C point from that picture. Now all i gotta figure out is where the rest of them go

Comment: Do you have a meter, or even a battery? A meter on ohms will make an audible crackle in the ear piece when connected across the wires. This can help you identify which wire is which.

Comment: Haven't had a meter, but i ended up referencing 2 pictures which worked quite well. These are the pictures in question in case someone needs it in the future:

http://www.eshopimage.com/netimg/201410/5213-5210/5213-5210-D2.jpg

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_rSc0zPNRAGQ/TTLC8eXRzgI/AAAAAAAABLs/q3I-yzoQusQ/s1600/wiring.jpg