# How to use a continuity test to differentiate between wires?

Tags: audio, multimeter, repair, headphones

I'm trying to repair my headphones with a broken jack. I just purchased a replacement TRRS jack, and now my problem is knowing the function of the five different wires in my earbuds. How can I use a multimeter to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Touching the ohmmeter to the pair of wires going to each earbud and ground should cause an audible pop and show low impedance.  The remaining non-ground wire would be for mic.  See [Fixing a headset, TRRS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/240685/fixing-a-headset-trrs?rq=1)

Comment: I just tried this and I can't seem to hear any audible noise. Does one lead need to be touching the ground wire and the other lead a different wire? I did this for each wire with no luck. Could it be the setting my Ohm Meter is on?

Comment: It is the current through the speaker that causes a pop, so you need one lead on the audio and the other on the return.  Depending on wiring, the return may be common or separate for the two sides.