# How to tell the difference between headphone wires?

Tags: audio, wire, repair, headphones

I'm trying to fix my TRRS type headphones but I can't tell the difference between these five wires.

-Blue
-Red
-Green
-Copper (red-ish?)
-Black

Comment: Make a nick in the wire jacket and beep it out with a multimeter.

Comment: Consider [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6698/headphone-wire-color-coding) question. Voted to close due for off topic: repair.

Comment: @Daniel modern headphone wires are sometimes very non-trivial to strip :)

Answer (score 5):

Wire color isn't standard. Never trust wire color. Always use a continuity tester to find which wire goes to which conductor.

Comment: +1. In a batch of 50 nominally identical headphones, same part number, purchased at the same time, I found four or five different colour coding standards used.