# What is this kind of audio cable called?

Tags: audio, identification, cables

I broke my headphone cable. It is exactly like the one in the image but I don't know how to search for this kind of audio cable (I only find cables with at least one receiving end). Does anyone know the name?

[image]

Comment: https://www.headphonesty.com/2019/04/headphone-jacks-plugs-explained/

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6698/headphone-wire-color-coding

Comment: from your pic having a breakout to green and red, that *should* be the left and right channels respectively from that 4 pole TRRS plug... the TRRS plug is basically universally used now giving the option of the mic in channel whether it is used or not.

Comment: doesn't look like any particular standard cable "headphone make/model cable" would probably be a good search term. You might be able to buy a cheap pair of headphones with an inline microphone, cut the headphones off and replace them with 2.5mm mono jacks?

Answer (score 4):

That's microphone and headphone cable combined, having a TRRS 3.5mm audio jack of unspecified pinout, with 2.5mm mono audio jacks at the other end.

There's no better name for it, and your picture sadly doesn't fully specify how the microphone and two stereo channels should be connected to the TRRS, which depends on the device you plug this into.

So: "headphone cable"?

Answer (score 4):

The end that appears closer in the picture is a 3.5mm TRRS (tip, ring, ring, sleeve) connector, while the other two connectors are both 3.5mm (most likely, it's hard to tell if they may be 2.5mm) TS (tip, sleeve). This means that if the cable is wired normally, the TRRS connector goes like this:

1. Tip = Left Audio (The hot lead on one of the TS connectors)
2. Ring = Right Audio (The hot lead on the other TS connector)
3. Ring = The grounds of each TS connector and the ground of the mic
4. Sleeve = Microphone (that's what that little thing most likely is inline with the cable)

Answer (score 0):

On a first look It is a TRRS 3.5mm splitter.  Being TRRS an abbreviation for tip, ring, ring and sleeve.

But since your are going to use this in a headphone I think you will be better served with the results of a 3.5mm TRS splitter or stereo splitter search. TRRS will be hard to find because the existing cables split the audio from the mic and it seems to me that it isn’t the case here.